# Change title of question in exsheets

Tags: exsheets

Is there any way to change the title of questions created with exsheets? I would like the title to be like "Lecture 1 - Exercise 1", instead of "Exercise 1".

Comment: The "Lecture" counter can behave like sections, so that when I write something like \lecture or \lecture{1}, all subsequent exercises will have the corresponding lecture number. However, if that is not possible, manually writing the numbers will also be ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a new counter `lecturecount` and increment it through a `\lecture` command.

Also, if you want the question counter to be reset at each lecture, load `exsheets` with the option `counter-within = lecturecount`.

Finally, redefine the `question` title by redefining the `question`-`solution` pair in this way

```
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[name=Lecture \thelecturecount\ -- Exercise]{solution}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{lecturecount}
\newcommand\lecture{\refstepcounter{lecturecount}}
\usepackage[counter-within = lecturecount]{exsheets}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[name=Lecture \thelecturecount\ -- Exercise]{solution}

\begin{document}

\lecture

\begin{question}
foo
\end{question}

\begin{question}
bar
\end{question}

\begin{question}
baz
\end{question}

\lecture

\begin{question}
foo
\end{question}

\begin{question}
bar
\end{question}

\begin{question}
baz
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @AakashJog you're welcome.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow skip a question number? I would like the second lecture to start from Exercise 2.

Comment: @AakashJog Put `\setcounter{question}{1}` just after the second `\lecture`